# Writing Regegular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am facing problem with Regular Expression and want to write that work for these conditions:

if a string is not starting with ++ and ** then match the pattern like:

> 45 www.google.com => **match**
>
> **MO 12:45:08 => **not match**
>
> ++ 110413  => **not match**

Any ideas?

Comment: How does this fit into the logic `MO 12:45:08 => not match`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have negative lookahead to check that:

```
^(?!\+\+|\*\*)
```

This matches any string that doesn't have `++` OR `**` at the start of the string by making use of negative lookahead `(?!...)`

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @KajalSingh: Added some explanation and doc link .

Comment: Simplified to a more understandable (and minimally sufficient) form.

Comment: @KajalSingh: Did this regex help you solve your problem?

Comment: @anubhava
:ya now its working.

Comment: ok perfect, whenever SO lets you, please mark the answer as accepted.